# Why DSL is giving score of 1.0 for query string search

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have data inside one index

Below is the first 3 documents, I have 111 documents. I am paring first 3 only

`q = {"size":3,"query":{ "match_all":{}}}`

```
{'took': 1, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 111, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': 1.0, 'hits': [{'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '0', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 0, 'Title': 'The Land Girls', 'US Gross': 146083, 'Worldwide Gross': 146083, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 8000000, 'Release Date': 'Jun 12 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Gramercy', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': None, 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': None, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': None, 'IMDB Rating': 6.1, 'IMDB Votes': 1071}}, {'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '1', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 1, 'Title': 'First Love, Last Rites', 'US Gross': 10876, 'Worldwide Gross': 10876, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 300000, 'Release Date': 'Aug 07 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Strand', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': 'Drama', 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': None, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': None, 'IMDB Rating': 6.9, 'IMDB Votes': 207}}, {'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '2', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 2, 'Title': 'I Married a Strange Person', 'US Gross': 203134, 'Worldwide Gross': 203134, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 250000, 'Release Date': 'Aug 28 1998', 'MPAA Rating': None, 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Lionsgate', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': 'Comedy', 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': None, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': None, 'IMDB Rating': 6.8, 'IMDB Votes': 865}}]}}
```

**Below query is giving _score of 1.0 for every document? why**

I am searching Live in elasticsearch

`query = {'from': 0, 'size': 30,  'query': {'bool': {'must': {'query_string': {'query': '**Live**'}}}}}`

My Output is below

```
{'took': 23, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 3, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': 1.0, 'hits': [{'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '11', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 11, 'Title': 'Oliver!', 'US Gross': 37402877, 'Worldwide Gross': 37402877, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 10000000, 'Release Date': 'Dec 11 1968', 'MPAA Rating': None, 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Sony Pictures', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': 'Musical', 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': None, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 84, 'IMDB Rating': 7.5, 'IMDB Votes': 9111}}, {'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '52', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 52, 'Title': 'Alive', 'US Gross': 36299670, 'Worldwide Gross': 36299670, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 32000000, 'Release Date': 'Jan 15 1993', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Walt Disney Pictures', 'Source': 'Based on Book/Short Story', 'Major Genre': 'Adventure', 'Creative Type': 'Dramatization', 'Director': 'Frank Marshall', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 71, 'IMDB Rating': 3.2, 'IMDB Votes': 124}}, {'_index': 'movie_data_01_03', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '90', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'id': 90, 'Title': 'The Best Years of Our Lives', 'US Gross': 23600000, 'Worldwide Gross': 23600000, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 2100000, 'Release Date': 'Nov 21 2046', 'MPAA Rating': None, 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'RKO Radio Pictures', 'Source': 'Based on Book/Short Story', 'Major Genre': 'Drama', 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': 'William Wyler', 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': 97, 'IMDB Rating': 8.2, 'IMDB Votes': 17338}}]}}
```

Comment: are you searching for `Live` word in your documents? What are you searching for in the documents shown above? Can you please tell that on hitting which search query are you getting a score 1.0

Comment: I m just searching *Live*  in the document . i have put * because i need to searchAlive, Lives. but  i got score 1.0 for every document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are searching for `**Live**` (i.e doing a wildcard search), in this by default a constant score is applied, due to which you are getting score of 1.0

You need to add [rewrite parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html), that will determine how the relevance score is calculated. Modify your search query as

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "**live**",
          "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66684902",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.3177552,
        "_source": {
          "id": 11,
          "Title": "Oliver!",
          "US Gross": 37402877,
          "Worldwide Gross": 37402877,
          "US DVD Sales": "None",
          "Production Budget": 10000000,
          "Release Date": "Dec 11 1968",
          "MPAA Rating": "None",
          "Running Time min": "None",
          "Distributor": "Sony Pictures",
          "Source": "None",
          "Major Genre": "Musical",
          "Creative Type": "None",
          "Director": "None",
          "Rotten Tomatoes Rating": 84,
          "IMDB Rating": 7.5,
          "IMDB Votes": 9111
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66684902",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.3177552,
        "_source": {
          "id": 52,
          "Title": "Alive",
          "US Gross": 36299670,
          "Worldwide Gross": 36299670,
          "US DVD Sales": "None",
          "Production Budget": 32000000,
          "Release Date": "Jan 15 1993",
          "MPAA Rating": "R",
          "Running Time min": "None",
          "Distributor": "Walt Disney Pictures",
          "Source": "Based on Book/Short Story",
          "Major Genre": "Adventure",
          "Creative Type": "Dramatization",
          "Director": "Frank Marshall",
          "Rotten Tomatoes Rating": 71,
          "IMDB Rating": 3.2,
          "IMDB Votes": 124
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66684902",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.64896965,
        "_source": {
          "id": 90,
          "Title": "The Best Years of Our Lives",
          "US Gross": 23600000,
          "Worldwide Gross": 23600000,
          "US DVD Sales": "None",
          "Production Budget": 2100000,
          "Release Date": "Nov 21 2046",
          "MPAA Rating": "None",
          "Running Time min": "None",
          "Distributor": "RKO Radio Pictures",
          "Source": "Based on Book/Short Story",
          "Major Genre": "Drama",
          "Creative Type": "None",
          "Director": "William Wyler",
          "Rotten Tomatoes Rating": 97,
          "IMDB Rating": 8.2,
          "IMDB Votes": 17338
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: all the scores are same, but i need it has to vary according to relevance

Comment: is there any way for that

Comment: @Nons all the scores are not the same if you see in the search result above the third document have a score of 0.64896965 whereas other two documents have the same score 1.3177552. First two documents will have the same score since one document contains `"Title": "Oliver!"` and `"Title": "Alive"`, occurrence of `live` in both the title fields is same.